The react project I am working on does not use a public folder but some prompts in the .gitlab-ci.yml file - need help understandig the pipeline
I was given a template to work with that I can modify but I lack the necessary understanding about the pipeline.
If anyone has the time, I would appreciate (also partial) explanations how the pipeline constructs the public folder and how I could change the project so I can put other files in the public folder, too.
I want to put a js file into the public folder in case that is relevant.
The project is currently structured like this:
├── README.md                       -> The file you are currently reading
├── index.html                      -> Single HTML file for the wiki
├── package.json                    -> Manages project metadata and dependencies
├── src/
│   ├── components/                 -> Components (Like Navbar, Timelines, ...)
│   ├── App/                        -> Main React application container
|   |     └── App.tsx
│   ├── contents/                   -> Page components for the website
│   │   └── *.tsx                   
│   ├── main.tsx                    -> Entry point of the wiki application
│   ├── pages.ts                    -> Page definition and path mapping
│   ├── utils/                      -> Utility functions
│   └── vite-env.d.ts               -> TypeScript definitions for Vite
├── tsconfig.json                   -> Configures TypeScript options
├── tsconfig.node.json              -> TypeScript settings for Node.js
├── vite.config.ts                  -> Configuration for the Vite tool
└── yarn.lock                       -> Yarn lock file for dependency management


This is the .gitlab-ci.yml file:
image: node:18.20.0

build:
  stage: build
  cache:
    - key:
        files:
          - yarn.lock
      paths:
        - .yarn-cache/
  before_script:
    - echo 'yarn-offline-mirror ".yarn-cache/"' >> .yarnrc
    - echo 'yarn-offline-mirror-pruning true' >> .yarnrc
    - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
  script:
    - yarn build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

pages:
  stage: build
  cache:
    - key:
        files:
          - yarn.lock
      paths:
        - .yarn-cache/
  before_script:
    - echo 'yarn-offline-mirror ".yarn-cache/"' >> .yarnrc
    - echo 'yarn-offline-mirror-pruning true' >> .yarnrc
    - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
  script:
    - yarn build
    - cp -a dist/. public/
    - echo '/* /index.html 200' > public/_redirects
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH


I read a few articles and basic instructions about pipelines, gitlab CI, vite and yarn. Unfortunately for me, this is not a very basic pipeline and it seems like it is always assumed that it is clear what expressions such as p -a in the yml file mean.
Using the classic "delete something and see what errors arise to figure out its purpose" approach, I figured out that - echo '/* /index.html 200' > public/_redirects makes all links to files in the public folder go to the index.html page (I think...).
And that cp -a dist/. public/ is necessary to find all the files to build the website with.
Therefore, I tried putting the js file into the project structure as follows
├── README.md                       -> The file you are currently reading
├── mapscript.js
├── index.html                      -> Single HTML file for the wiki

Alas, that did not lead to it being found.
Edit / further info
I figured I just have to get the mapscript.js to be published somehow... so I created a folder whose contents are moved to the public directory on build.
It is in the structure like this:
├── README.md                       -> The file you are currently reading 
├── pubpub  
├──   └── mapscript.js
├── index.html                      -> Single HTML file for the wiki
├── package.json 

And changed the pages/script part of the xml file like:
script:
    - yarn build
    - mv dist public

And added the folder in the vite.config.js:
export default () => {
  const env = loadEnv("dev", process.cwd());
  return defineConfig({
    base: `/${stringToSlug(env.VITE_TEAM_NAME)}/`,
    plugins: [react()],
    build: {
      outDir: "dist",
    },
    publicDir: 'pubpub',
  });
};

That worked more or less.
More, because mapscript.js has now a valid url I can use.
Less, because the pages of the website were sent to 404 not found on reload or if I just entered the url. In other word, they were only reachable when coming from the homepage and using the navigation bar.
To change that I added a line of the original yml back:
script:
    - yarn build
    - mv dist public
    - echo '/* /index.html 200' > public/_redirects

And now they are reachable again.
One thing is still not working.
Trying to reach the home page with this link works still: https://2024.igem.wiki/bielefeld-cebitec/ but not the original link https://2024.igem.wiki/bielefeld-cebitec/index.html .
Still have to figure out how I messed that up and how to reverse it.
And I still do not really understand the pipeline and how everything is published. I just tried a lot of things that seemed to make sense until one worked and gave mapscript.js a reachable url.

Can you explain what you mean when you say "that did not lead to it being found"? Where did you expect to find the js file?

@MichaelKotzjan Yes, sure.
When importing a script via a script tag, the source of the script has to be a valid url and not a local file, because it does not find a local file after the build (for reasons that I do not know).
By putting it in the same folder as the index.html, I hoped it would become a public file with an url on build but that did not work out = it was not found.
As you see, I am quite clueless on how the pipeline I was given is supposed to work and the team that created the pipeline is of no help with this issue so far.

I solved it this way:
Build script:
script:
    - yarn build
    - mv dist public

pages script:
script:
    - yarn build
    - mv dist public 
    - echo '/* /index.html 200' > public/_redirects 

vite.confog.js:
export default () => {
  const env = loadEnv("dev", process.cwd());
  if (!env.VITE_TEAM_NAME) {
    throw new Error("VITE_TEAM_NAME environment variable is not defined");
  }

  const baseSlug = stringToSlug(env.VITE_TEAM_NAME);
  console.log(`Base URL: /${baseSlug}/`);
  console.log(`Output directory: ${path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')}`);

  

  return defineConfig({
    base: `/`,
    plugins: [react()],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), // Simplifies imports
      }
    },
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        css: {
          //javascriptEnabled: true, // Enable JavaScript in CSS (useful for certain CSS preprocessor plugins)
        }
      }    },
    build: {
      outDir: "dist",
      rollupOptions: {
        output: {
          assetFileNames: `assets/[ext]/[name]-[hash].[ext]`
          }      
        }
      },
    publicDir: 'pubpub',
  });
};

Now it is working. Well it was until I changed something else today haha. But that has nothing to do with this error, that was completely resolved.

I'm not that familiar with pages myself, but as far as I understand the documentation the part that made index.html available was the line
echo '/* /index.html 200' > public/_redirects

in the script section of the pages job. This line writes /* /index.html 200 to the file public/_redirects. According to the documentation of this file it can be used to redirect requests. In your case every request to any page (/*) would redirect to the index page. This is also explained in this part of the documentation.
I suspect that rules are handled in order so I would suggest to try to set a rule before the general redirect to serve your js file:
script:
    - yarn build
    - cp -a dist/. public/
    - echo '/scripts/mapscript.js /mapscript.js 200' > public/_redirects
    - echo '/* /index.html 200' > public/_redirects

This should allow you to access the js file via /scripts/mapscript.js as long as the file is placed next to index.html on the same level.
The documentation also gives us a way to "debug" the redirect rules by accessing /_redirects like this: https://2024.igem.wiki/bielefeld-cebitec/_redirects
It shows that you currently have one active rule and it is valid. You can check this after you added another rule.
This is unfortunately a completely untested answer, I hope it helps you!
